# Navigation text won't change colour when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

Link: http://jdfill.me/nrmc/

When you load the page, the navigation text is white, which it should be. When you scroll down, I've made it so the text is grey, which is great.

However when you scroll back up to the very top of the browser, the navigation text doesn't go back to white. Instead, it stays grey.

How can I make the navigation text white, when you scroll back to the top of the browser?

Comment: Please add the code that you have used to make the color transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTop()` function to check whether the user have scrolled back to top of the page.

```
$(document).on("scroll",function()
    {               
    if($("body").scrollTop()===0)
    {
    //function for changing the color
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should have the text on a page be white when you  are within 50 pixels from the top of the page, but will change the color to grey anywhere else that is not within 50 pixels from the top of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollcolor() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
            document.getElementById("text").style.color = "white";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("text").style.color = "grey";
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollcolor);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code which get fired on window scroll and check the top offset of the top-bar-container element. if less than equal to 89 then it gives all the nav except first link white color.

I have tested this with your website page, hope this helps

```
   $(window).on("scroll",function(){

   if($(".top-bar-container").offset().top <= 89)
   {
      $("#menu-main-nav li a").not(":first").css("color","#ffffff")
   }
   else
   {
     $("#menu-main-nav li a").css("color","#333333")

   }    
   })
```